# setState vs replaceState in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.js Library and I was going over some of the tutorials and I came across:

- `this.setState`
- `this.replaceState`

The Description given is not very clear (IMO).

```
setState is done to 'set' the state of a value, even if its already set 
in the 'getInitialState' function.
```

Similarly,

```
The replaceState() method is for when you want to clear out the values 
already in state, and add new ones.
```

I tried **`this.setState({data: someArray});`** followed by **`this.replaceState({test: someArray});`** and then console.logged them and I found that `state` now had both `data` and `test`.

Then, I tried **`this.setState({data: someArray});`** followed by **`this.setState({test: someArray});`** and then console.logged them and I found that `state` again had both `data` and `test`.

So, what exactly is the difference between the two ?

Comment: Your first example is inaccurate.  replaceState would remove the previous state.  You're likely testing it incorrectly.

Comment: I was not looking for changes in a callback. Maybe that's why..

Answer (score 152, accepted):

With `setState` the current and previous states are merged.  With `replaceState`, it throws out the current state, and replaces it with only what you provide.  Usually `setState` is used unless you really need to remove keys for some reason; but setting them to false/null is usually a more explicit tactic.

While it's possible it could change; replaceState currently uses the object passed as the state, i.e. `replaceState(x)`, and once it's set `this.state === x`.  This is a little lighter than `setState`, so it could be used as an optimization if thousands of components are setting their states frequently.
 <sub>I asserted this with [this test case](http://jsbin.com/doqimeva/1/edit?js,output).</sub>

---

If your current state is `{a: 1}`, and you call `this.setState({b: 2})`; when the state is applied, it will be `{a: 1, b: 2}`.  If you called `this.replaceState({b: 2})` your state would be `{b: 2}`.

Side note: State isn't set instantly, so don't do `this.setState({b: 1}); console.log(this.state)` when testing.

Comment: Still unclear to me. Can you give an example where using one over the other changes the result, ie this merging that you're referring to...

Comment: How is there a previous state and a current state, as in, how can we access them ? Also, I did pass an object to replace state, but yet the previous state data was still present.

Comment: So when is the state set ? As in when can I console.log it and test it ?

Comment: @myusuf `.setState({...}, callback)`

Answer (score 49):

Definition by example:

```
// let's say that this.state is {foo: 42}

this.setState({bar: 117})

// this.state is now {foo: 42, bar: 117}

this.setState({foo: 43})

// this.state is now {foo: 43, bar: 117}

this.replaceState({baz: "hello"})

// this.state. is now {baz: "hello"}
```

Take note of this from the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html), though:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.

Same goes for `replaceState()`

Answer (score 14):

According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#replacestate), `replaceState` might get deprecated:

> This method is not available on ES6 class components that extend React.Component. It may be removed entirely in a future version of React.

Comment: Is there a replacement method that is similar?

Comment: For a "similar" method, you could use this.setState({all:undefined,old:undefined,keys:undefined,new:value})

Comment: @Wren, what is this? Is this official signature to reset state?

Comment: No, it's just explicitly setting the pre-existing state to undefined which is the net result of "replaceState" without all of the extant keys.

Answer (score 2):

Since `replaceState` is now deprecated, here is a very simple workaround. Though it is probably quite seldom that you would / should resort to needing this.

To remove the state:

```
for (const old_key of Object.keys(this.state))
    this.setState({ [old_key]: undefined });
```

Or, alternatively, if you don't want to have multiple calls to `setState`

```
const new_state = {};
for (const old_key of Object.keys(this.state))
    new_state[old_key] = undefined;
this.setState(new_state);
```

Essentially, all previous keys in the state now return `undefined`, which can very easily be filtered with an `if` statement:

```
if (this.state.some_old_key) {
    // work with key
} else {
    // key is undefined (has been removed)
}

if ( ! this.state.some_old_key) {
    // key is undefined (has been removed)
} else {
    // work with key
}
```

In JSX:

```
render() {
    return <div>
        { this.state.some_old_key ? "The state remains" : "The state is gone" }
    </div>
}
```

Finally, to "replace" the state, simply combine the new state object with a copy of the old state that has been `undefined`, and set it as state:

```
const new_state = {new_key1: "value1", new_key2: "value2"};
const state = this.state;

for (const old_key of Object.keys(state))
    state[old_key] = undefined;

for (const new_key of Object.keys(new_state))
    state[new_key] = new_state[new_key];

this.setState(state);
```