# React Redux Router - adding a new query param without losing the old one

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I am trying to add query params to an URL which already have other query params, but instead of adding a new query param it removes the old one and keeps only current one. e.g:

```
hashHistory.push({
  articleId: `?s=${articleId}`,
});
```

after this url becomes: http://example.com/#/?articleId=23

but later if I try to add another query param from another component:

```
hashHistory.push({
  userId: `?s=${userId}`,
});
```

it will be: http://example.com/#/?userId=5 so articleId is removed.

One way to keep old params is to pass articleId back to the component where userId is assigned, but I have deeply nested components and this is not convenient, is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: Is there a way to get current query params? If there is, you can get them, then add or override the parameter you want, and then push the updated query parameter list/map.

Comment: Yes that is one way to go, but as mentioned it requires a lot of unnecessary checking of parameters, also a lot of additional props.

Comment: I meant if you can get the current list/map of parameters, and alter it to include the parameter you want, you don’t have to do any checking whatsoever. Just add/overwrite the parameter you want. Something like `hashHistory.push(currentParameters.set('userId', …))`. That way, you don’t  have to fiddle with anything except the parameters your component cares about and still preserve the other ones.

Comment: getting currentParameters is a problem I am talking about, otherwise it is dead simple.

Comment: Which `react-router` version are you using? You can get parameters injected to your component via props since `v2.0.0`. See https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#injected-props

Comment: Yes I am getting it with props, but as the application is quite big, I have to pass props in a lot of components, so that is the thing I dont want to do, but looks like I have to.

Comment: You’re right. The only solution I can think of is to pass parameters via context, but that’s experimental feature and also a bit tricky to use.

Anyways, I use it in my projects and it’s good enough, except it’s non-trivial to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` because you have to make assumptions whether your children use context or not.

More about context: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setState vs replaceState in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293626/setstate-vs-replacestate-in-react-js)